# Привет! Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять откуда подтягивается реклама на сайт!

Tags: javascript, html, css, реклама

В общем я верстаю сайт, размещаю его на хосте и все хорошо, рекламы нет, потом обновляю страницу (2-5 раз) и появляется реклама как на картинке ниже. Обновлю страницу она пропадёт, а через несколько обновлений опять появиться. Сначала я грешил на Бутсреп или Джейквери, а сегодня я захожу на ВордПресс, продолжаю делать сайт и при обновление у меня вылазит эта реклама в ВордПресе, тут я понял что дело тут в чем-то другом. Может в браузере Гугл хром, но у меня на телефоне Фаерфокс и тоже такую рекламу выдает иногда. Самое интересное что рекламу выдает не всегда, а через рандомное число обновлений! В общем не знаю что делать! ПАМАГИТЕ (^_^)/[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Протокол http или https? Если http, то провайдеры любят добавлять в незащищённый канал связи свою рекламу и скрипты статиститики. Не используйте http на публичных сайтах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вероятно, хостеры, а не провайдеры.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хостеры тоже. Но от рекламы хостера избавиться нелегко. А от рекламы провайдера избавиться можно, если защитить протокол.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, если бы мне провайдер за мои деньги ещё и рекламу пихал, пошёл бы он лесом...

Comment: @Qwertiy, мобильные провайдеры в метро этим и промышляют. Известный факт. В аэропортах. Везде где вам предлагают залогинится на бесплатный WiFi.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хм.. ну я б не стал бесплатный вайфай называть провайдером... И вряд ли автор кодит свой сайт в метро ;)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, у меня хост на beget. Вроде норм фирма. Звонил в поддержку, они сказали что рекламу не вставляют... 
Сейчас начал чекать на телефоне: с вайфаем и с мобильным инетом. Так вот на мобильном инете обновил раз 30 и ничего не вылезло, а на вайфае вылезло. Буду еще завтра тестить! Спасибо вам за идеи!!!

Comment: @Qwertiy, Ростелеком, хана тебе .!.

Comment: @Kirill, расширения для браузера проверь, особенно для vpn. И попробуй в приватном окне, где все расширения по умолчанию отключены.

Comment: очевидно крякнутый шаблон для вордпрес скачал, вот там и реклама, искать в js

Comment: [Ростелеком раньше точно промышлял такими вещами](https://habr.com/ru/articles/493402/), видимо и до сих пор продолжает

Answer (score 1):

Реклама появляется от провайдера Ростелеком!

Comment: _Какие ваши доказательства?_ (с)

Comment: @Nowhere Man, Потому что когда использую сайт на мобильном интернете, реклама не вылазит. Тестил 2 дня. На вайфае вылазит в среднем каждые 5-7 обновлений, а на мобильном интернете за 2 дня не было ни разу!

Comment: Уже 4 дня сам тестирую и дал сайт друзьям. Так вот у тех у кого ростелеком на сайт вставляется реклама, с мобильного интернета или другого оператор, рекламы нет. Сегодня подключил на сайт HTTPS и проблему решил окончательно!